# Navigation Bar Current state

Tags: css

Hi everyone I made a navigation for my website. I just like to change the color of my links when I go to another page. For example I click the "about" then I will go to about page I like the about link will turn to red when I am in the about page.

How can I do that? 
Thank you!

Here the codes

html

```
<nav> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Creatives For Less</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

nav ul {
    font-family: josefin;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 11pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 15px;

}

nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0ff;
}

nav li a:hover, a:active {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! If you ask a question, it helps if you include the things you've tried, the constraints you're working with, etc. Note that you can edit your question to add those details.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Are you saying you want "about" to be red because of the fact that you're currently viewing the "about" page, or because you have at some point view the "about" page. In other words, if you (from the about page) clicked on the link to the "index" page, on the new page that loads, would "Home" be red, or "About", or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some css class with javascript or with some server-side language.

If you'll use javascript you should find something that indicates you that user is on about page (some div with information for example). And then, if you use JQuery, add this class:

```
$('#mylink').addClass('active');
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing this; using JQuery for such trivial things should probably be avoided as general practice.

Answer (score 2):

Just have an `active` class, and if you're on a page, set the `<li>` to have that class.

For example:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
```

And in your css style the `active` class:

```
nav li.active a{
    color: red;
}
```

If you're asking how you know which page you're on, though, and want to do it dynamically, you'll need to use PHP, some other server-side language or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use the a:visited in your CSS.

a:visited
{
background-color:yellow;
}

You should look into setting classes for them too and then assigning them via the css